# Angular How to check HttpRequest object to set proper content-type for headers?

Tags: json, angular, http

My team is working for some time on rewriting front-end of our application to Angular. Everything was going more or less smoothly until I encountered file importing views. Our default `HttpHeaderEnricherInterceptor` is setting default `Content-Type` as `application\json`. It works well in the whole application but while trying to import any file all I get is 415. However, if I remove `.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')` importing is working properly... but all other components are failing. I was trying to make some if statements based on `HttpRequest` params but it doesn't recognize `has()` method and some others that I've tried.

I know that final option to solve this is to set content-type on each request but it's something I would like, better avoid it as we decided to try finding global solution to the problem.

Here's my `intercept()` code:

```
import { TokenService } from './../token/token.service';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HttpHeaderEnricherInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(`${req.url}?${req.params.toString()}`);

    const changedReq = req.clone(
      {headers:  req.headers
        .set('Authorization',  this.tokenService.getToken() || '')
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      });
    return next.handle(changedReq);
  }
}
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: angular serializes the object and sets the content type header to json *by default* when posting/putting an object. Setting it in an interceptor is useless. The client code, sending the request, should specify the appropriate content type (if needed). The interceptor can't possibly guess what is being sent.

Comment: Well that's something that's something that was I was afraid to hear. However thanks for the quick response, I'll watch on the thread suggested by @kemsky and Angular team to see if there will be any further improvment in that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is already opened issue on Github: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19730

Workarounds are possible but ugly, i.e. global boolean flag switching before and after call, adding fake header as indicator i.e.:

```
if(headers.get('X-Set-Content-Type') != null){
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. We will probably stick to defining content type on post. However thanks for the thread link, I'll keep an eye on it.